# (VBA) apply to all, except one specific

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Hi everyone i made a button on excel using VBA modules,The code works on the active sheet but what im looking for is to be applied to more sheets, not just the active sheet where the button is placed.

```
Sub Botón1_Haga_clic_en()
    Call Worksheet_Calculate
End Sub


'apply cells colors from single-cell formula dependencies/links
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Dim Cel       As Range
    Dim RefCel  As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each Cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Cel.HasFormula Then
            Set RefCel = Evaluate(Mid(Cel.Formula, 2))
            Cel.Interior.Color = RefCel.Interior.Color
        End If
    Next Cel

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below :

```
Option Explicit

Sub Botón1_Haga_clic_en()

Dim wsName As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

wsName = ActiveSheet.Name

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not ws.Name Like wsName Then '<-- is worksheet's name doesn't equal the ActiveSheet's
        ApplyCellColors ws ' <-- call you Sub, with the worksheet object
    End If
Next ws

End Sub

'=======================================================================    
'apply cells colors from single-cell formula dependencies/links

Private Sub ApplyCellColors(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim Cel       As Range
    Dim RefCel  As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each Cel In ws.UsedRange
        If Cel.HasFormula Then
            Set RefCel = Evaluate(Mid(Cel.Formula, 2))
            Cel.Interior.Color = RefCel.Interior.Color
        End If
    Next Cel

End Sub
```

Comment: Good works like a charm :D

The button can be protected with password to captcha to avoid an accidental use?

Thanks!

Comment: @Sebastian  you're welcome, thanks for accepting as answer

Comment: You can password protect the button for accidental or false execution?

Comment: @Sebastian  sounds like a great new **SO** post

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be translated to something like *How to loop over all sheets and ignore one of them?*

This is a good way to do it:

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim wks As Worksheet

    For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wks.name = "main" Then
            Debug.Print "Do nothing here, this is the active sheet's name"
        Else
            Debug.Print wks.name
        End If

    Next wks

End Sub
```

Pretty sure, that you should be able to fit it in your code.